# H2 DB file is getting corrupted in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, h2

I am currently using the H2 DB File storage with Spring boot. The ORM is a JPA. The connection are completely handled by Spring boot

I have the below setting in my application.properties file

```
spring.jpa.show-sql = false
spring.main.allow-circular-references=true
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ant_path_matcher
#To beautify or pretty print the SQL
#It manipulates the database schema at startup
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
#It is used to reconnect and synchronize detached entities with active PersistenceContext so that
#changes performed on them could be reflected onto the database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.event.merge.entity_copy_observer=allow
#To specify any property that isn't in the default spring.jpa expected properties use this
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false
#This entry is put just to avoid a warning message in the logs when you start the spring-boot application
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
#It is used to make SpringBoot load orm.xml
spring.jpa.orm=orm.xml
#Fully qualified name of the physical naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
#Fully qualified name of the implicit naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl

#h2 db properties
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:./DBfile ;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=FALSE;
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

When ever the application writes to DB and server restarts the DB file is getting corrupted.  This would happen when the connection could not release the lock on the file. Is there any configuration which can solve this problem?

Any help would be appreciated.

DB file should not be corrupted when the server restarts.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered similar issue recently, still not 100% sure I have fixed my issue, but after using `:async`, `DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1` and `AUTO_SERVER=TRUE`, it has been performing stably for a while now.

you may try:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:async:./DBfile ;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=FALSE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE
```

Hope it is of help and also wish I have fixed my own issue.